# reactjs - how to get data from a child component into onclick of a button passed in props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS and ES2015

I pass a button via props down into a child component.

I can't see how to get data from the child into the onClick function of the button

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get data from the child component into the onCLick function?

```
  doDeleteItem = (blah) => {
    console.log('the item to delete is: ', blah);
  };


  deleteButton = (
      <button
       className="btn btn-expand btn-stroke btn-success mr-5"
       type="primary"
       onClick={this.doDeleteItem}Delete item
     </button>
   )

   render() {
     return (
       <TableContainer
         deleteButton={this.deleteButton}
         doDeleteItem={this.doDeleteItem}
       />
     );
```

**UPDATE: the comments say it's a bit unclear.
Here's the context:**

The TableContainer component displays rows of data.

I push Button components down into the TableContainer via props.

The TableContainer renders the buttons.

I also push a function down for the Button to call in its onClick event.

The idea being that the user selects rows in the table, they push the button (such as delete for example) and the button runs its onClick function which deletes the selected rows.

The problem is that I can't see how to get the data that defines the selected rows into the onClick function.

It appears that the "scope" of the onClick function is actually the parent component, not the TableContainer component, so it cannot see the variables the define which data rows the user has chosen to delete.

Is that more clear? Let me know if not.  thanks

Comment: I'm editing my own comment. You want data from TableContainer into `testButton`?

Comment: Could you please expand upon that @Henrik?

Comment: Somewhat unclear. do you need this onClick={this.doDeleteItem.bind(this,item)} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define `doDeleteItem`, `deleteButton` as methods instead of properties, and then call `deleteButton` in child and pass arguments what do you need

```
doDeleteItem(rows) {
    console.log('the item to delete is: ', rows)
};

deleteButton(rows) {
  return <button
    className="btn btn-expand btn-stroke btn-success mr-5"
    type="primary"
    onClick={ () => this.doDeleteItem(rows) }
  >
    Delete item
  </button> 
}

render() {
  return (
    <TableContainer
      deleteButton={ this.deleteButton }
      doDeleteItem={this.doDeleteItem}
   />
 );
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/30816/)

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass down the parent function to the child as a property and separate the button component from the parent completely. You can include this button component in the child component (although it would be best to separate this component from child also) and insert the parent function there. If you want to pass parameters, you need to bind the function.

Parent:

```
doDeleteItem = (blah) => {
    console.log('the item to delete is: ', blah);
};

render() {
    const locale = this.props.app.locale;

return (
    <TableContainer
    onButtonClick={this.doDeleteItem.bind(this, blah)}
    doDeleteTableItem={this.doDeleteTableItem}
    />
);
```

Child (TableContainer):

```
render() {
    var deleteButton = (
        <button
        onClick={this.props.onButtonClick}
        </button>
    )
return (
    // render TableContainer with deleteButton ..
);
```

Comment: The reason I want to push the buttons and their handler functions down to the TableContainer is because the TableContainer is generic and is used throughout my application to display rows of data.  Whereever the TableContainer is used, different buttons are displayed and different onClick functions need to be executed against the selected table rows. In fact the way you describe is the way it works right now and I am trying to move the buttons up out of the table container to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

As @WitVault mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312208/reactjs-how-to-get-data-from-a-child-component-into-onclick-of-a-button-passed#comment58334462_35312208) you could pass some reference from the onClick in deleteButton so that the table knows which one to delete.

```
deleteButton = (
  <button
    className="btn btn-expand btn-stroke btn-success mr-5"
    type="primary"
    onClick={() => this.doDeleteItem(referenceToMeSoTableKnows)}>
      Delete item
  </button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `deleteButton` is getting called for just returing jsx. So you must be using it inside render method of `TableContainer` to render buttons.

and since here

```
<TableContainer
      deleteButton={ this.deleteButton() }
      doDeleteItem={this.doDeleteItem}
   />
```

`doDeleteItem` is passed as props inside `TableContainer`. you can access it via `this.props` inside `TableContainer`. Note this scope should be referring to scope of `TableContainer` so that you can access its `props`.

```
deleteButton = (
      <button
       className="btn btn-expand btn-stroke btn-success mr-5"
       type="primary"
       onClick={this.props.doDeleteItem.bind(this,item)}
     </button>
   )
```

I hope this should work.